# Sorting Perl with Class::DBI

Tags: perl, class-dbi

You have the following table called Pets:

```
name     age     pet
------------------------
Carol     25     null
Stean     23     cat
Mel       24     dog
Rich      24     rabbit
```

In a MySQL database on the server mydbserver with the user of 'user' with a 
password of 'password'.

Do the following:

1) Create a `Class::DBI` connection to this database with the above credentials ( DBI.pm ).

2) Create a Class for the table Pets ( Pet.pm )

3) Create a program that prints all the names of people in the Pets table and what kind (if any )
of pet he/she has sorted by name then age.

Here is the code I wrote.....

```
#!/usr/bin/perl      
package Pet::DBI;
use DBI;
use strict;
use base 'Class::DBI';
Pet::DBI->set_db('Main','dbi:mysql:dname', 'user', 'password') 

or die $DBI::errstr "\n";
1;

package Pet::Pets;
use base 'Pet::DBI';
use strict;
use warning;
Pet::Pets->table('Pets');
Pet::Pets->columns(All => qw/name age pet/);
1;

use Pet::Pets;
my @pets = Pet::Pets->retrieve_all; 
for (sort {$a->name cmp $b->name} || {$a->age <=> $b->age}  @Pets) {
print "Name:".$_->name ' => '."Age". $_->age"\n";
}

1;
```

Comment: If at all possible, consider [DBIx::Class](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBIx::Class).  Class::DBI is no longer maintained and isn't a very good ORM by modern standards.  I should know, [I wrote it](https://metacpan.org/pod/release/MSCHWERN/Class-DBI-0.02/lib/Class/DBI.pm).  Also, is this homework?  If it is, please let the teacher know the author says to stop using Class::DBI. :)  Finally, the Class::DBI documentation already contains [an example of doing exactly this](https://metacpan.org/pod/Class::DBI#How-to-set-it-up).

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately they are insisting on using Class::DBI and not DBIx::Class as the app used it.

Comment: I would like to know the answer to the 3 question. I got the first 2 questions.

Comment: Who are "they"? And why are they insisting on using supported software? That doesn't sound like good advice?

Comment: @Dave Cross I agree but what do you think about sorting using Class::dbi ?

Comment: I think two things. I think that a) Schwern has already given you a good answer and b) a teaching environment should not be teaching obsolete software.

Answer (score 1):

It's basically correct, but there's a number of small problems.

It's not necessary to load DBI, Class::DBI will take care of that for you.

You should be using [`connection`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Class::DBI#connection) instead of `set_db("Main", ...)`.  `set_db` comes from Ima::DBI and it's not polite (or necessary) to peek under the hood like that.

Although this isn't directly documented in Class::DBI (it should be), its inherited from [Ima::DBI](https://metacpan.org/pod/Ima::DBI#set_db), there's no need to check for DBI errors.  [RaiseError](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI#RaiseError) is on and if the connection fails it will throw an error.

You have a typo, `use warning;` instead of `use warnings;`.

Unless you have stitched three files together for the post, if the code is all in one file the `1;` statements do nothing.  `use Pet::Pets` will not work because there is no `Pet/Pets.pm` file.  You don't have to use a class which is already in the same file.

In general, avoid using `$_` if you don't have to, too many things can quietly use or change it.  Instead, give the for loop a proper variable like `for my $person`.

`sort` only takes one block, but you're basically correct.  It should be `sort { ($a->name cmp $b->name) || ($a->age <=> $b->age) }  @Pets`

To avoid reading the whole, potentially very large, table into memory, the sorting should really be done in the database with an `ORDER BY name ASC, age ASC` and then retrieved a row at a time using an [iterator](https://metacpan.org/pod/Class::DBI#ITERATORS).  Unfortunately, [retrieve_all](https://metacpan.org/pod/Class::DBI#retrieve_all) does not support any options.  You can use `retrieve_from_sql` to add arbitrary SQL to the end of the basic SELECT.  `my $all_people = Pet::Pets->retrieve_from_sql("ORDER BY name ASC, age ASC");`  Then your data will already be sorted and can be read a row at a time.  `while( my $person = $all_people->next ) { ... }`

You're missing a `.` in `"Age". $_->age"\n"`.

Null values in a database come back as undef.  You'll want to check if `$_->pet` is defined and if not use some other string like `"no pet"` or just a blank `""`.

You're printing the person's age, the question asks for their pet.

Otherwise, it should work.

But really, tell whomever gave you this homework to stop telling people to use Class::DBI.  They can email me if they like, schwern@pobox.com.

Comment: Thanks Schwern, the sorting question confuses me how can you sort the name of the pet owner and then sort the same with the age? Wouldn't one take precedence over the other and lose the order? Also the entity using it is a great fan of your class::dbi  !

Comment: @user_falafel I see the mistake in your sort call now.  You have it basically correct, but the syntax is wrong.  I've edited my answer.  If the entity is a huge fan, then they'll please honor my request to stop teaching people to use it.  It's no longer a useful real world ORM, its no longer maintained, and teaches some bad habits.  Case in point, loading the whole table into memory because there is no way to pass in sorting options to retrieve_all.

Comment: I figured out a better way to retrieve all rows with an ORDER BY.

Comment: I did use the order by ASC on name  using an iterator and the next method but they didn't like the answer and wanted me to not use an iterator. So, I decided  to use an array , retrieve and store all the rows and then sort the object in ASC and print them.

Comment: @user_falafel You had it right. `retrieve_all` should basically never be used, and iterators used whenever possible.  Unless you know you're going to only get a limited data set back, like with a LIMIT clause, you should never fetch all the rows from a database at once.  It risks consuming all your memory and leaves you open to a DOS attack.  They're teaching you bad practices on an obsolete ORM, I hope you're not paying them much.  I'd be interested to see the course materials and critique them.

Comment: Agreed, they are using obsolete ORM  for production in a teaching / education environment. I FLUNKED this test according to them.Thanks for your feedback!